# Substitute previous row value if value equal to 0 in Python

Tags: python

I want to check if the value of a column in a dataframe is equal to 0 and if it is 0, I want to substitute the previous row's value of that column.

Suppose my data is as follows,

```
               X
683           24.48
684           24.48
685           24.48
686           24.48
687           24.48
688           24.48
689           25.02
690           25.02
691           25.02
692           25.02
693           25.02
694           25.02
695           25.02
696           25.02
697           25.32
698           25.32
699           25.32
700            0.00
701            0.00
702            0.00
703            0.00
704            0.00
705            0.00
706            0.00
707            0.00
708            0.00
709            0.00
710            0.00
711            0.00
712            0.00
713            0.00
714            0.00
715            0.00
716            0.00
717            0.00
718            0.00
719            0.00
720            0.00
721            0.00
722            0.00
723            0.00
724            0.00
725            0.00
726            0.00
727            0.00
728            0.00
729            0.00
730            0.00
731            0.00
732            0.00
733            0.00
734            0.00
735            0.00
736            0.00
737            0.00
738            0.00
739            0.00
740            0.00
741            0.00
742            0.00
743            0.00
744            0.00
745            0.00
746            0.00
747            0.00
748            0.00
749            0.00
750            0.00
751            0.00
752            0.00
753            0.00
754            0.00
755            0.00
756            0.00
757            0.00
758            0.00
759            0.00
760            0.00
761            0.00
762            0.00
763            0.00
764            0.00
765            0.00
766            0.00
767            0.00
768            0.00
769            0.00
770            0.00
771            0.00
772            0.00
773            0.00
774            0.00
775            0.00
776            0.00
777            0.00
778            0.00
779            0.00
780            0.00
781            0.00
782            0.00
783            0.00
784            0.00
785            0.00
786            0.00
787            0.00
788            0.00
789            0.00
790            0.00
791            0.00
792            0.00
793            0.00
794            0.00
795            0.00
796            0.00
797            0.00
798            0.00
799            0.00
800            0.00
801            0.00
802            0.00
803            0.00
804            0.00
805            0.00
806            0.00
807            0.00
808            0.00
809            0.00
810            0.00
811            0.00
812            0.00
813            0.00
814            0.00
815            0.00
816            0.00
817            0.00
818            0.00
819            0.00
820            0.00
821            0.00
822            0.00
823            0.00
824            0.00
825            0.00
826            0.00
827            0.00
828            0.00
829            0.00
830            0.00
831            0.00
832            0.00
833            0.00
834            0.00
835            0.00
836            0.00
837            0.00
838            0.00
839            0.00
840            0.00
841            0.00
842            0.00
843            0.00
844            0.00
845            0.00
846            0.00
847            0.00
848            0.00
849            0.00
850            0.00
851            0.00
852            0.00
853            0.00
854            0.00
855            0.00
856            0.00
857            0.00
858            0.00
859            0.00
860            0.00
861            0.00
862            0.00
863            0.00
864            0.00
865            0.00
866            0.00
867            0.00
868            0.00
869            0.00
870            0.00
871            0.00
872            0.00
873            0.00
874            0.00
875            0.00
876            0.00
877            0.00
878            0.00
879            0.00
880            0.00
881            0.00
882            0.00
883            0.00
884            0.00
885            0.00
886            0.00
887            0.00
888            0.00
889            0.00
890            0.00
891            0.00
892            0.00
893            0.00
894            0.00
895            0.00
896            0.00
897            0.00
898            0.00
899            0.00
900            0.00
901            0.00
902            0.00
903            0.00
904            0.00
905            0.00
906            0.00
907            0.00
908            0.00
909            0.00
910            0.00
911            0.00
912            0.00
913            0.00
914            0.00
915            0.00
916            0.00
917            0.00
918            0.00
919            0.00
920            0.00
921            0.00
922            0.00
923            0.00
924            0.00
925            0.00
926            0.00
927            0.00
928            0.00
929            0.00
930            0.00
931            0.00
932            0.00
933            0.00
934            0.00
935            0.00
936            0.00
937            0.00
938            0.00
939            0.00
940            0.00
941            0.00
942            0.00
943            0.00
944            0.00
945            0.00
946            0.00
947            0.00
948            0.00
949            0.00
950            0.00
951            0.00
952            0.00
953            0.00
954            0.00
955            0.00
956            0.00
957            0.00
958            0.00
959            0.00
960            0.00
961            0.00
962            0.00
963            0.00
964            0.00
965            0.00
966            0.00
967            0.00
968            0.00
969            0.00
970            0.00
971            0.00
972            0.00
973            0.00
974            0.00
975            0.00
976            0.00
977            0.00
978            0.00
979            0.00
980            0.00
981            0.00
982            0.00
983            0.00
984            0.00
985            0.00
986            0.00
987            0.00
988            0.00
989            0.00
990            0.00
991            0.00
992            0.00
993            0.00
994            0.00
995            0.00
996            0.00
997            0.00
998            0.00
999            0.00
1000           0.00
1001           0.00
1002           0.00
1003           0.00
1004           0.00
1005           0.00
1006           0.00
1007           0.00
1008           0.00
1009           0.00
1010           0.00
1011           0.00
1012           0.00
1013           0.00
1014           0.00
1015           0.00
1016           0.00
1017           0.00
1018           0.00
1019           0.00
1020           0.00
1021           0.00
1022           0.00
1023           0.00
1024           0.00
1025           0.00
1026           0.00
1027           0.00
1028           0.00
1029           0.00
1030           0.00
1031           0.00
1032           0.00
1033           0.00
1034           0.00
1035           0.00
1036           0.00
1037           0.00
1038           0.00
1039           0.00
1040           0.00
1041           0.00
1042           0.00
1043           0.00
1044           0.00
1045           0.00
1046           0.00
1047           0.00
1048           0.00
1049           0.00
1050           0.00
1051           0.00
1052           0.00
1053           0.00
1054           0.00
1055           0.00
1056           0.00
1057           0.00
1058           0.00
1059           0.00
1060           0.00
1061           0.00
1062           0.00
1063           0.00
1064           0.00
1065           0.00
1066           0.00
1067           0.00
1068           0.00
1069           0.00
1070           0.00
1071           0.00
1072           0.00
1073           0.00
1074           0.00
1075           0.00
1076           0.00
1077           0.00
1078           0.00
1079           0.00
1080           0.00
1081           0.00
1082           0.00
1083           0.00
1084           0.00
1085           0.00
1086           0.00
1087           0.00
1088           0.00
1089           0.00
1090           0.00
1091           0.00
1092           0.00
1093           0.00
1094           0.00
1095           0.00
1096           0.00
1097           0.00
1098           0.00
1099           0.00
1100           0.00
1101           0.00
1102           0.00
1103           0.00
1104           0.00
1105           0.00
1106           0.00
1107           0.00
1108           0.00
1109           0.00
1110           0.00
1111           0.00
1112           0.00
1113           0.00
1114           0.00
1115           0.00
1116           0.00
1117           0.00
1118           0.00
1119           0.00
1120           0.00
1121           0.00
1122           0.00
1123           0.00
1124           0.00
1125           0.00
1126           0.00
1127           0.00
1128           0.00
1129           0.00
1130           0.00
1131           0.00
1132           0.00
1133           0.00
1134           0.00
1135           0.00
1136           0.00
1137           0.00
1138           0.00
1139           0.00
1140           0.00
1141           0.00
1142           0.00
1143           0.00
1144           0.00
1145           0.00
1146           0.00
1147           0.00
1148           0.00
1149           0.00
1150           0.00
1151           0.00
1152           0.00
1153           0.00
1154           0.00
1155           0.00
1156           0.00
1157           0.00
1158           0.00
1159           0.00
1160           0.00
1161           0.00
1162           0.00
1163           0.00
1164           0.00
1165           0.00
1166           0.00
1167           0.00
1168           0.00
1169           0.00
1170           0.00
1171           0.00
1172           0.00
1173           0.00
1174           0.00
1175           0.00
1176           0.00
1177           0.00
1178           0.00
1179           0.00
1180           0.00
1181           0.00
1182           0.00
1183           0.00
1184           0.00
1185           0.00
1186           0.00
1187           0.00
1188           0.00
1189           0.00
1190           0.00
1191           0.00
1192           0.00
1193           0.00
1194           0.00
1195           0.00
1196           0.00
1197           0.00
1198          26.16
1199          26.16
1200          26.16
1201          26.34
```

Here in the 0s, I want the 25.32 value. The point is, initially my data starts at 0.

How can we do this in Python? I am able to do this in R. The following is the command I used,

```
library(zoo)
is.na(DF$a) <- DF$a == 0
DF$a        <- na.locf(DF$a,na.rm=FALSE)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, should all the 0.00 values become 25.32?

Comment: If you are looking for a Python answer, there's no need to tag it with R

Comment: @andrew No.. I am looking for the previous value.. No all the 0s should become 25.32

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the method ffill.

Assuming you don't have NaN (or also want to fill in NaN in the same way as 0):

```
df = df.replace(0, np.NaN).ffill()
```

If you do have NaN and want keep NaN as is:

```
df.loc[~df.x.isnull(), 'x'] = df.loc[~df.x.isnull(), 'x'].replace(0, np.NaN).ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, provided you are willing to use numpy:

First, identify the indices which meet your condition using the `where` function. (Assuming that you already have your data in an array, called `x` in this case)

`indices = np.where(x == 0.0)[0]`

The use of `[0]` in the previous line is necessary because calling `where` without the optional replacement values returns a tuple with one element: an array of the indices where the condition is met (see the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for more info).

To replace the the zeroes with the previous non-zero:

```
for index in indices:
    c[index] = c[index - 1]
```

This will automatically leave leading zeroes in place, and only correct the gaps after there have been non-zero values.

Comment: I am not looking to replace all the zeros with 25.32.. I am looking to replace it with the previous value. Here since the previous value is 25.32, I uses that example.

Comment: @haimen ahh, got it. I've corrected my answer and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1: you only want to substitute the first row with a 0.00 value:

```
a = range(1, 10)
a = a + [0,0,0,0,0]
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
out = [a[0]] + [x if x !=0 else y for x,y in zip(a[1:], a[:-1])]
# out = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So now we have a list with two 9 values. The first zero has been replaced.

NOTE: I am assuming you cannot replace a 0 value in the first row.

Version 2: you want to substitute all 0.0 values, even if the previous row was substituted.

```
a = range(1, 10)
a = a + [0,0,0,0,0]
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
out = [a[0]]
for x in a[1:]:
    if x != 0:
        out.append(x)
    else:
        out.append(out[-1])
# out =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Now all the 0 values have taken the last non-zero value.

Version 3: based on the op's feedback:

```
import itertools
a = [0,0,1,2,5,4,0,0,8,9,0,5,0,6]
# accept all leading zeros
out = [x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == 0, a[1:])]
for x in a[len(out):]:
    if x != 0:
        out.append(x)
    else:
        out.append(out[-1]))
```

Really though, the **best solution** in my opnion, especially if you are familiar with R, is to use the [Python Pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/missing_data.html). See the "Fill gaps forward or backward" section. The solution is much more elegant than trying to do it all with native packages.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, If I want to substitute all the values other than the first value with the previous value, how do I do that?

Comment: I just made a small edit, `a = range(1,10)`.  Using my original list example, `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, can you show me what the final list should look like?

Comment: Suppose a=[0,0,1,2,5,6,0,0,8,9,0,11,0,13], Output should be a=[0,0,1,2,5,6,6,6,8,9,9,11,11,13] 

This is what I am looking at....